# Adding Custom httpStatus to Kubernetes Virtual Service

Tags: kubernetes, http-status-code-404, istio, envoyproxy

I am deploying a virtual service on Kubernetes using which I want to expose a host. This host will target the elastic search DB and allow read only operations on it. Every other CRUD operation should be blocked.
After blocking I get 404 Not Found HTTP Response but I want to customize it to HTTP 405: Method Not Found.
Any suggestions on achieving this? Attached is the virtual service YAML file used in kubernetes

Tried

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: read-es-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "readonlyelastic.com"
  gateways:
  - istio-system/default-gateway 
 
  http:
  
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
      method:
        exact: GET
    route: 
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8080
        host: elasticsearch-master-data
    
     fault:
        abort:
           httpStatus: 405
```

But it didnot give the expected result

Comment: You could use an `EnvoyFilter` if that's an option.

Comment: Try `delay` instead of `abort` in `fault`

Comment: Hi, Have you tried based on the above comments? If you issue has been resolved; please post your solution so, that it will be useful for the other community members.